# what is the content-type when there are uploadables in graphql?

Tags: typescript, fetch

i am using typescript and this is my fetch query config for headers:

```
const getHeaders = (uploadables: UploadableMap | null | undefined) => {
  if (uploadables) {
    return { Accept: "*/*" };
  }
  return { Accept: "application/json", "Content-type": "application/json" };
};

  const headers = {
    ...getHeaders(uploadables),
    ...(token && { Authorization: token }),
  };
```

the problem is typescript want "Content-type" defined, and i am not sure what to put when headers' Accept is "* / *"?

Answer (score 0):

weird, resolved by doing this:

```
const headers = {
    ...(uploadables
      ? { Accept: "*/*" }
      : { Accept: "application/json", "Content-type": "application/json" }),
    ...(token && { Authorization: token }),
  };
```